# How to Check for a missing variable In JS?

Tags: javascript, forms, onsubmit

I am trying to check if a variable exists before allowing the form to submit.

Currently, the user enters the address into the form and autocomplete adds lat and long to the form. I wrote the following js

```
function check() {
    let latitude = document.getElementById("latitude").value;
    if (latitude == null) {
        window.prompt("ned a correct address", "");
        return false;
    } else {
        alert('It worked');
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I submit an address that doesn't have the lat and long autocompleted I am still getting "it worked"

Here is my form

```
<form method="GET" action="/search" onsubmit="check()">
    <input class="form-control" id="getaddy" type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="term" onFocus="geo()">
    <input id="latitude" type="hidden" name="latitude">
    <input id="longitude" type="hidden" name="longitude">
</form>
```

Comment: When you debug this code, what is the value of `latitude` at the conditional in the scenario you described?

Comment: @csmckelvey corrected error in answer below :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to check if a variable exists or not, there is a safe way to do so, by using:

```
if(variable) {
  // Truthy
} else {
  // Falsy
}
```

This way, you get all the possible `Falsy` scenarios including: `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, `""`, `0` and finally the `false` itself... Without checking for each one of them!

Here is the edited snippet:

```js
function check() {
  let latitude = document.getElementById("latitude").value;
  if (latitude) {
    alert('It worked');
    return true;
  } else {
    window.prompt("ned a correct address", "");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="GET" action="/search" onsubmit="check()">
  <input class="form-control" id="getaddy" type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="term" onFocus="geo()">
  <input id="latitude" type="hidden" name="latitude">
  <input id="longitude" type="hidden" name="longitude">
</form>
```

***This code will execute ONCE only!**

Comment: If you were interested in brevity, you could simply do `return !!latitude` instead of the entire `if` portion :) You'd lose the alert though.

Comment: Amazing! This did it. Thanks so much

Comment: The OP isn't really testing for whether a variable exists, but whether something has been entered into a form control. In that case, the value should be tested according to suitable criterial, so `if (latitude == '')` would be preferred as when the  test is executed, its value must be a string. Though it would also be better to test `-90 <= latitude <= +90`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to consider here for more reliable form validation;

1. Suggest using the event object to cancel the submit action if validation fails
2. Validate input fields value via a test for the "empty string" rather than `null`
3. Ensure no errors are thrown in your script (ie ensure `geo()` is defined, etc) so that `check()` actually gets called rather than silently failing to be called due to another script error

The following changes might help:

```js
// Pass event object
function check(event) {
  
  let address = document.getElementById("getaddy").value;
  
  // Check for empty string, rather than null
  if (address === '') { 
    window.prompt("ned a correct address", "");
      
    // Use Event#preventDefault() to prevent submit
    // as a more reliable alternative to returning 
    // false
    event.preventDefault();
  } else {
  
    alert('It worked');
  }
}


// Ensure geo() is defined, seeing your form is relying on this
function geo() { }
```

```html
<!-- update check call to pass event object -->
<form method="GET" action="/search" onsubmit="check(event)">

  <input class="form-control" id="getaddy" type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="term" onFocus="geo()">
  <input id="latitude" type="hidden" name="latitude">
  <input id="longitude" type="hidden" name="longitude">
  
</form>
```